# htaccess rewrite conditions depending of variables for mobile sites

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Hi i have a site with drupal and i use a module for make redirection depending of the agent, if mobile redirect to http://m.url.com but if no, stay in desktop site, but i want to redirect always to http://www.url.com if you write url.com for this, i use this

```
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}[L,R=301]
```

but this no works for me, because i use a module to redirect to mobile site, then, if use the code before always redirect to www.url.com but in mobile also, redirect to www.m.url.com and no working for mobile site, please how to make a exception in the code before, always redirect to www.url.com except m.url.com

thanks

**Solution**

with the answer before, i resolve for this way

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^url.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m.url.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:www|m)\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: ok works, finding solution and works, and i find before other solution and also workings